# math domain error (linalg) in statsmodels.tsa.api.VAR

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I am trying to use Vector Auto Regression (VAR), but I got this error: ValueError: math domain error

Here is my code: (and also I don't know how to give it only one dimensional data)

```
    Y = [data[0,:] , data[1,:]]

    import statsmodels.tsa.api
    Vmodel = statsmodels.tsa.api.VAR(Y)


    results = Vmodel.fit(2)
    results.summary()
    results.plot()
    results.plot_acorr()
```

Here is the Error message:

```
Traceback:

\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\myproj\mainProg.py", line 190, in AR

results = Vmodel.fit(4)

\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\vector_ar\var_model.py", line 443, in fit

return self._estimate_var(lags, trend=trend)

\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1837, in lstsq

nlvl = max( 0, int( math.log( float(min(m, n))/2. ) ) + 1 )
```

My data type is numpy array of floats.

Thanks for your help.

Update:
Solved by transposing the input data!

Comment: try `Y = data[:2, :].T`, assuming your data has observations in the columns. I think your rows are the variables and not observations. I guess either m or n is zero, math.log(0).

Comment: @user333700 you can post your comment as an answer...